# xslt code requirement

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt code,need a code for the below requirement.

in the input xml I am receiving one xml tag name as sbdh__name

in output I need that xml tag name as sbdh:name

is there any standard xslt code to achieve this and also wherever those "__" symbols are need to replace with ":" I tried few xslt codes but I am getting errors. can anyone suggest on this?
Regards,
Janardhan

Regards,
Janardhan

Comment: **1.** Please post a [mcve]. **2.** You cannot replace a character in element name with `:` because the `:` character is reserved for separating the namespace prefix from the local name. You probably want to recreate those elements with a new name.

Comment: Before you start coding, I suggest you do some reading. Read about how XSLT manipulates node trees rather than lexical XML; and read about namespaces. You need to understand the concepts of the language before you can write code; in fact you need to understand the concepts so that you can use the right terminology when asking questions, and when trying to understand the answers.